# Binding Height to another control working backwards

Tags: c#, wpf

I have the following code:

code behind:

```
public MainWindow()
{
    InitializeComponent();
    DispatcherTimer timer = new DispatcherTimer();
    timer.Interval = new TimeSpan(0, 0, 5);
    timer.Tick += Timer_Tick;
    timer.Start();
}

private void Timer_Tick(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
    List<ItemType> list = new List<ItemType>();
    list.Add(new ItemType() { typeId = 263, typeName = "Test A" });
    list.Add(new ItemType() { typeId = 264, typeName = "Test B" });
    itemTreeView.ItemsSource = list;
}
```

xaml:

```
<TreeView DockPanel.Dock="Bottom" x:Name="itemTreeView" Margin="0">
   <TreeView.Resources>
        <DataTemplate DataType="{x:Type local:ItemType}">
            <StackPanel Orientation="Horizontal">
                 <Image Source="{Binding typeImage}" Height="{Binding ActualHeight, ElementName=tname, Mode=OneWay}"/>
                 <TextBlock Text="{Binding ActualHeight, ElementName=tname}"/>
                 <TextBlock x:Name="tname" Text="{Binding typeName}"  ToolTip="{Binding description}"/>
             </StackPanel>
         </DataTemplate>
    </TreeView.Resources>
```

And it was working fine in early development but now that I am pushing things a little harder whenever it seems to update more frequently the binding appears to work backwards changing the `ActualHeight` of the `TextBlock` to the height of the image. I added the `Mode="OneWay` portion thinking that would maybe help prevent this but it is still happening. I end up with the image and panel with a height of 64px when appears to be 16 typically (I don't want to set a fixed value in case a user has bigger font sizes set. It seems to stop shrinking the image on the second reload.
The binding to typeImage is going to bind to a 64x64 `BitmapSource`

Comment: _"it seems to update more frequently the binding appears to work backwards changing the ActualHeight of the TextBlock to the height of the image"_ -- it may seem that way, but I'm sure it's not. The `ActualHeight` property is read-only, so it's not possible that it could be getting set by the binding. Probably, the `TextBlock` height gets increased by the container to accommodate the natural height of the `Image`. Unfortunately, without a good [mcve] in your question, it's not possible for anyone else to reproduce the behavior, never mind suggest a fix. Please improve your question.

Comment: @PeterDuniho finally had a chance to take your advise. Hope the question is better now.

Answer (score 0):

I was able to fix it by adding `VerticalAlignment="Top"` to `<TextBlock x:Name="tname" Text="{Binding typeName}"  ToolTip="{Binding description}"/>` preventing the textblock from stretching if the image loaded first.